I'm using webview_flutter 4.9.0, but I couldn't find how to implement "pull to refresh" feature
I've googled it a couple of hours of pull to refresh feature, but coudn't find it yet.
Some of them say to use RefreshIndicator but didn't work to webview_flutter.
And I've found this
How can i pull to refresh webview in flutter
but I guess the version of webview_flutter on this article is different from what I use, 4.9.0
can anyone find a solution so far?
If I have a question on this webview_flutter plugin, where can I ask to?
Thank you in advance.
googled about this issue for a couple of hours. and red quite many articles on stackoverflow.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Unfortunately, I gave up on using Flutter and moved on to Kotlin. It is currently being prepared for distribution. Anyway, thank you for your reply.
